# Create new database from a MariaDB backup

Tags: mariadb, database-backups, backup-strategies

I have a large database (over 150GB and growing) in production. Currently I make a full back up of it using the `mariabackup` command, and then twice a day I do incremental backups of the database.

I need to make a development version of the database and would like to use the backup I already have for it. From the documentation I've found for the command it seems the restoration of it is straightforward but effectively replaces what is there. I can't see anything that allows me to change the name of the database and effectively create a new one from the backup. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Its slightly manual, but from [partial backup and restore](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partial-backup-and-restore-with-mariabackup/):

At the prepare stage use `--export`

```
 mariadb-backup --prepare --export \
   --target-dir=/var/mariadb/backup/
```

Then you need to have a `dev` database with all the tables there with discarded tablespaces. Creating tables can be done with `mariadb-dump --no-data prod | mariadb dev`. Discarding tables spaces is `ALTER TABLE tablename DISCARD TABLESPACE`. I haven't seen an easy automation for this. Will need '   SET SESSION foreign_key_checks=0;' if there are foreign key constraints on the table.

Copy the tablespaces from the backup:

```
scp /var/backup/prod/*.{cfg,ibd} db:/datadir/mariadb/dev/
```

Then for all the tables:

```
use dev;
ALTER TABLE tablename IMPORT TABLESPACE;
...
```

Partitioned tables are [more complicated](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-file-per-table-tablespaces/#importing-transportable-tablespaces-for-partitioned-tables).

Note for MariaDB-11.2, no `CREATE TABLE` or `DISCARD TABLESPACE` is needed, however the `.frm` table structure file should be copied.